# What could ever be wrong with the following mySql code?

Tags: mysql, decimal

The following is the most basic and simplest code I ever wrote, what could be wrong with that code?

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","myroot","mydb");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    else
      {
       echo "Connecting to server Localhost succeeded ! ";
      }
    // Add column

    $sql="ALTER TABLE june2013 ADD time_interval (DECIMAL(5,2))";
    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
       {
        echo "Column added successfully";
       }
    else
       {
        echo "Error creating database: " . mysqli_error($con);
       }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I get an error message that says:

> Connecting to server Localhost succeeded !!! Error creating database: You have an error      in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(DECIMAL(5,2))' at line 1

Any idea why I'm getting this?

Answer (score 1):

Could it just be that you are missing "COLUMN" from the statement?

$sql="ALTER TABLE june2013 ADD time_interval (DECIMAL(5,2))";

should be

$sql="ALTER TABLE june2013 ADD COLUMN time_interval DECIMAL(5,2)";

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work either. I changed "(DECIMAL(5,2)" to "NUMERIC(5,2)" and that was no good either.

Comment: Hi user1662701 I removed the brackets from (DECIMAL(5,2) [code]$sql="ALTER TABLE june2013 ADD time_interval DECIMAL(5,2)";[/code] and it works !! Thanks again.